# Remove a div by id with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$.grep(arrayPintar, function(el) {
    if ($.inArray(el, arrayVariables) == -1) 
        difference2.push(el);

    //  arrayPintar.pop(el);
    var identificador = difference2.pop();
    if ((identificador != null) || (arrayVariables.length == 0)) {
        $("div#container div#" + identificador + "").remove();
    }          
});
```

I can't remove all elements from `#container` because when my array variables is empty, `grep` returns an execution error (`length can not be  null`).

Are there any other ways to compare two arrays and return the different elements?

Thank you in advance for your time and attention.

Comment: Add `HTML` code also

Comment: Remove Space between `div#" +`